# What is the difference between sys.dm_hadr_ tables and sys.availability_groups / sys.availability_replicas?

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, high-availability, hadr

Browsing around some sys tables, I see:

`sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_nodes.group_name = sys.availability_groups.name`

and

`sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_nodes.replica_server_name = sys.availability_replicas.replica_server_name`

and

`sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_nodes.node_name = sys.availability_replicas.replica_server_name`

and

`sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states.group_id = sys.availability_groups.group_id`

Could someone please clarify for me whether the "*hadr*" tables are duplicating data or not? For example, `sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_nodes` and `sys.avilability_replicas` sound like they're describing the same thing.

I guess the question is on how safe it is to join these tables given I can see data values equate - because after all, the same value (something like 'SQL01') could conceivably be used to describe different things.

Better yet - is there no entity-relationship diagram published by Microsoft for these sys tables? I can find old posts where people ask the same question about ERDs and there are answers regarding older versions of SQL Server, but all links to diagrams seem outdated and defunct.

Comment: I guess broadly I'm wondering whether the HADR tables were implemented as a set, and if so, what's the history there (what were they implemented for that wasn't already in place with the other tables)? And if so, did they extend the existing tables or duplicate some functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It's not duplicating of the information, depending on the requirement we could utilize anyone them:

1. DMV: The prefix `sys.dm_` represents **DMV** the under lying information from Dynamic Management views
2. Catalog View: No prefix `sys.` represents **catalog views**. [For more details..](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1948e8a4-500d-4993-8013-cc41ba37790b/difference-between-dynamic-management-views-and-catalog-views?forum=transactsql)